# Как сделать управление как в "Get Over It"?

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, физика, элементы-управления

Допустим круг это конец молота. Также как я понял есть другой круг, к которому тянется молот. Игрок по сути двигает второй круг (назовём магнитом), а молот притягивается к нему. Но как быть с препятствиями? Какой командой и физикой двигать магнит, чтобы он не проходил сквозь препятствия и при этом управление над ним не прекращалось. Заморочено написал, короче: через что реализовать управление как в этой игре?

Comment: мало кто играл в твою игру. Хочешь что бы тебе помогли - оформь сначала вопрос так что бы человек который его увидит понял про что ты говоришь и не затратил дополнительных усилий на его понимание. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask